# Inheritance: Call the correct method at runtime depending on the concrete object

Tags: c#, inheritance

I´ve got the following classes:

```
public class Person
{
}

public class Employee : Person
{
}

public class Customer : Person
{
}
```

Some methods that use these classes:

```
public class OtherClass
{
    public void DoSomething(Employee e)
    {
    }

    public void DoSomething(Customer c)
    {
    }
}
```

The call:

```
// People = Collection<Person>.
foreach (var p in People)
    DoSomething(p); // Should call the right method at runtime and "see" if it´s an Employee or a Customer.
```

The compiler does not allow this. How do I implement this scenario?

Comment: How to do that because it doesn´t work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach here is polymorphism, i.e.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual void DoSomething() {} // perhaps abstract?
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public override void DoSomething() {...}
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    public override void DoSomething() {...}
}
```

and use:

```
foreach (var p in People)
    p.DoSomething();
```

---

HOWEVER! If that isn't possible, then cheat:

```
foreach (var p in People)
    DoSomething((dynamic)p); // TADA!
```

---

Another option would be to check the type yourself:

```
public void DoSomething(Person p)
{
    Employee e = p as Employee;
    if(e != null) DoSomething(e);
    else {
        Customer c = p as Customer;
        if(c != null) DoSomething(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that. DoSomething() is not part of the base class. It´s a member of another external class.

Comment: @tkrause k, then the 1st option might be possible; the 2nd/3rd options should work fine, though

Comment: Type checking is what we DO NOT want. Because every time you create new types you have to touch that code again. We thought it should work without it.

Comment: @tkrause why should it? in pretty much every type-based language I can think of, that wouldn't compile in the way you intend - why would it be different for C#? However: did you try the `dynamic` option, which forces the system to do exactly what you have asked?

Comment: @tkrause er, yes it should; what happens? (edit: [here we go](http://pastie.org/4913718), works fine)

Comment: Wow... the dynamic thing works now. We had to add Microsoft.CSharp.dll! THANKS!!!!